# Accepting Any SSL Certificate Causes My Program to Hang

Tags: http, ssl, dart

I have the following dart program:

```dart
import "dart:io";
import "dart:convert" show UTF8;

void main() {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.badCertificateCallback = (certificate, host, callbackPort) {
    print("In bad certificate callback.");
    return true;
  };
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.self.signed.url.com/api")).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    print("In request callback.");
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse resp) {
    print("In responce callback.");
  });
}
```

This code makes a get request to a url. The url uses a self signed certificate, which results in an SSL error. To get around this I have set the `badCertificateCallback` of `HttpClient` to always return true, effectively accepting all certificates.

With this code I would expect to see following output:

```
In request callback.
In bad certificate callback.
In responce callback.
```

And then have the program exit. Instead I see:

```
In bad certificate callback.
In request callback.
```

And the program hangs. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have submitted a Dart bug as advised by some of the comments. It can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21128). If anything comes of that I'll put the results back into this.

Comment: Accepting any SSL certificate admits strangers to your living room. It's already insecure. You're not really entitled to complain about the results.

Comment: I think I am allowed to ask why the program hangs. Yes, this is a very bad idea for a production app/server however for a little personal project I don't think I should have to bother to get the certificates set up while I'm prototyping.

Comment: Have you tried to make the request with another client? Maybe the server is not responding, and the vm is waiting for the response.

Comment: @luizmineo I wrote the equivalent code in Java and it worked fine. The server is up and I can get a response.

Comment: well, according to the [API docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpClient), your code is correct. I think you should file an issue at http://dartbug.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it has nothing with HTTPS to do, but with the handling of the HTTP protocol on the https://checkmate.fogbugz.com/api.xml server. The Dart HTTP stack send all headers field names in lower case. This is not handled correctly by the server.

The following code illustrates this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  SecureSocket.connect("checkmate.fogbugz.com", 443).then((socket) {
    socket.write("GET /api.xml HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                 "host: checkmate.fogbugz.com\r\n"
                 "\r\n");
    socket.listen((data) => print(UTF8.decode(data)));
  });
}
```

No response is ever received. If `host:` is changed to `Host:` the response is received.

[RFC 2616 section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) states: 'Field names are case-insensitive.'